# How to create Azure Devops service connection using system.accesstoken in a script

Tags: azure, azure-devops, access-token, rbac

I want to create a "Service Connection" using system.accesstoken of Azure devops instead of using "PAT" of the user.
what are the permissions that should be given to system.accesstoken to create a service connection.

I tried giving all the access to "Project Collection Build Service ({OrgName})", "{Project Name} Build Service ({Org Name})" identities. But it did not work.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to define role on service connection security tab for `Project Collection Build Service (account)`:

[image]

[image]

Comment: which role should it be given to that role?

Comment: i have given both creator and administrator roles but it doesn't create a "Service Connection" by using system.accesstoken